# Audio issue during zoom calls

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, audio, bluetooth, zoom-meeting

I've a Sony WH-XB910N bluetooth headset which I use a few months ago.

Since a few weeks ago I started to have audio issues with it during zoom calls. I just don't hear anything and zoom displays message about poor internet connection.

- video is always good, so I'm not sure it's indeed internet connection
- people don't complain not hearing me, also I'm not using the headset's microphone, but another one (Logitech webcam's mic.)
- the issue happens pretty often in zoom, however never in Teams with the same device settings
- when I switch from the headset to computer's speaker during a call, it gets better, although not perfect
- if I start the meeting already with speakers then the issue doesn't occur
- I've tried updating drivers, didn't help
- I can't upgrade my OS
- I can try having wired connection to the internet, however it requires quite a bit of work

[image]

My setup:

- HP Elitebook 850 G7
- Windows 10 Enterprise, 22H2 build 19045.3208
- connected to internet through wireless

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Zoom?

Comment: not yet, I'll try and let you know whether it helps.